# Finding which service has run an executable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-services

I was wondering if it were possible to find out which windows service has run an executable?

I've got two different services running from the same exe, doing different things. The main method of the program detects a command line parameter and will either start the console app (if running in Environment.UserInteractive), or start one of the two possible services. I can't find a good way to discern which service is running so I can choose the correct service to start in the code. Passing in .exe parameters in the image path of the windows service doesn't seem to work. The services are running on a server and starting automatically, so doing it manually isn't really an option.

I'd really like to avoid having to have two different projects with different executables, so any way I can notify the program of which service to run would be great.

Comment: So you mean you have a service Service.exe, and if you start it with -foo it behaves one way, and if you pass -bar it behaves in another way, and the problem is sometimes one of them may be running but you don't know which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arguments in the `ImagePath`.  I know I have done it at some point using a .net windows service, but as I recall, I had to install the service using something other than the standard .Net installer.

The .Net installer adds quotes around whatever you pass, which makes ImagePath go from `C:\test\test.exe -arguments` to `"C:\test\test.exe -arguments"` when it should be `"C:\test\test.exe" -arguments`.

Check out [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_serviceinstall.htm), [sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) or [CreateService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the correct registry value.

To test, install your service as usual and browse in regedit to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\yourServiceName` and edit ImagePath.  For an example of how it should look, check out `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\seclogon`.

Answer (score 0):

Have your service share its start state( temp file, registry key or other method, it could even write this as html to a web server... )

```
ServiceController yourService = new ServiceController( "YourServiceName" , "YourMachine" );
if( yourService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped )
{
    yourService.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) in your service at the point it starts, using a name unique to the version it is running. If the mutex is obtained then you know it isn't running. If it can't be obtained then the service is already running.

You could then start your services through a new process that first tries to obtain the mutex for the first service and if it can't obtain it it starts the second.

So, you start ServiceRunner.exe -foo. A mutex called "foo" is obtained, so you release the Mutex and ServiceRunner.exe starts Service.exe -foo.

If the mutex is not obtained you then try to obtain a mutex called "bar" and follow the same process.

This is a nasty solution, and would require your to create a new exe that simply tries to start the services.